# Json paring with Recycler view

Tags: java, android, json

Here I am trying to display the name and price of the test.
and I'm taking a recycler view to do the same using the JET Parsing GET method.
But I'm not getting anything in my business and showing myself black there.
here is my code
please help me find the solution.

Model class

```
        public class TestListsModel {

        public String test_price;

        public String testlist_id;

        public String test_name;
    }
```

This is my Adapter:

```
public class AdapterTestList  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        List<TestListsModel> data= Collections.emptyList();
        TestListsModel current;
        int currentPos=0;

        // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
        public AdapterTestList(Context context, List<TestListsModel> data){
            this.context=context;
            inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.data=data;
        }

        // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_list_row, parent,false);
            MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        // Bind data
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
            MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
            TestListsModel current=data.get(position);
            myHolder.testName.setText(current.test_name);
            myHolder.testPrice.setText( current.test_price);


            // load image into imageview using glide
           /* Glide.with(context).load("http://192.168.1.7/test/images/" + current.fishImage)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                    .into(myHolder.ivFish);*/

        }

        // return total item from List
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }


        class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView testName;
            TextView testPrice;

            // create constructor to get widget reference
            public MyHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                testName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_name);
                testPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_name);

            }

        }

    }
```

This is my Activity Class:

```
public class HealthServicesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

            SharePreferenceManager<LoginModel> sharePreferenceManager;

            // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
            public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
            public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
            private RecyclerView testListRecylerView;
            private AdapterTestList mAdapter;

         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_health_services);
                ButterKnife.bind(this);

                sharePreferenceManager = new SharePreferenceManager<>(getApplicationContext());

                dayTimeDisplay();

                new AsyncLogin().execute();
            }

 private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        //ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
          /*  pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();*/

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                String url_test="http://192.168.1.80/aoplnew/api/users/gettestlist/"+sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class).getResult().getCenterId();
                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                //url = new URL("http://192.168.1.7/test/example.json");
                url = new URL(url_test);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("[]");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            //pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<TestListsModel> data=new ArrayList<>();

            //pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    TestListsModel testData = new TestListsModel();
                    testData.testlist_id= json_data.getString("testlist_id");
                    testData.test_name= json_data.getString("test_name");
                    testData.test_price= json_data.getString("test_price");

                    data.add(testData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                testListRecylerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.test_list_recycler_view);
                mAdapter = new AdapterTestList(HealthServicesActivity.this, data);
                testListRecylerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                testListRecylerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(HealthServicesActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(HealthServicesActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: Have you checked if your data list is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `setLayoutManager` before the setting the adapter like below. In your code, you have `setAdapter()` before the `setLayoutManager` therefore your adapter not set properly.

Refer this for the further explanation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

```
    testListRecylerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.test_list_recycler_view);


    mAdapter =  new AdapterTestList(HealthServicesActivity.this, data);
    /**
     * SET THE LAYOUT MANAGER BEFORE SETTING THE ADAPTER
     */

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(HealthServicesActivity.this);
    testListRecylerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    testListRecylerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

     /**
      * AND THAN SET THE ADAPTER 
      */

    testListRecylerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: have applied the same but still its showing me blank activity

Comment: @Sujal i have updated the code..Please check it once and let me know in case of concern

Comment: ya i have applied the same code but when i checked my data size  its showing me zero .how to resolve this

Comment: @Sujal what is your response is coming from the server? can u please add it

Comment: @Sujal Have u fixed the issue?

Comment: Its your Service issue..I have just rectified the code which was wrong...Whenever u get the response than please let me know where are u stucked

Comment: still i am getting data size 0

Comment: Can u please post the response which u are getting from the server...u need to check the response from the code..u are missing something while calling the service..if on postman u are getting response and in ur code u are not getting any response than there is something error in the service calling

Comment: @Sujal has your problem fixed

Comment: Ya have fixed the problem .there is some mistake in my Poko class that's why it's showing me list size zero. Thank you for your help  :) @ravindra kushwaha